# How do I install PHP 5.5 on a new version of CentOS or Amazon Linux or Redhat or Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, php, amazon-ec2

I just joined a new company. I've been asked to build a CI/CD pipeline for a Laravel app. It is very fragile. It was built for PHP 5.5 and it breaks when they've tried to upgrade to 5.6 or 7. They don't have the time or resources to repair the app, or modernize it any way. Therefore we must keep running PHP 5.5.

On Amazon, I"m free to spin up any kind of EC2 instance. I can run with Redhat or CentOS or Ubuntu or Amazon Linux. But once I've launched the instance, I need to find a way to install PHP 5.5. Does anyone know which of these different flavors of Linux is the most likely to support PHP 5.5? I think most of these run newer versions of PHP by default, so I would need to downgrade the versions. Can anyone point me to information about that?

Comment: The [last 5.5 release was in July 2016](https://www.php.net/releases/index.php). 5.5 is likely to contain a number of well-known security problems. I'd suggest not doing this.

Comment: We have no option. The whole company depends on the PHP 5.5. The app breaks when we try to upgrade to 5.6 or PHP 7. We are stuck with 5.5. We have a plan to upgrade the software, but we believe it will take a year to implement. So for the next year, we must find a way to install and run 5.5.

Comment: If you depend on the application, it's probably doubly wise not to run it on ancient software.

Comment: Again, it will take a year to upgrade the code, so we need to find a way to install PHP 5.5 for the next year.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to achieve this is build 5.5 from sources with necessary extensions and FPM, install it under `/opt` and configure your webserver to use this particular FPM instance for your vhost.

This way you won't break anything php-related on your host and there's no need to deal with ancient packages wrecking havoc in your package manager.

Comment: " won't break anything php-related on your host " -- We are spinning up a new EC2 instance for this. I can use any Linux distro that I want. I can use Redhat or CentOS or Ubuntu. I'm doing everything from scratch so there is no risk of breaking something. Can you point me to a tutorial about installing PHP from scratch, on any Linux bistro?

Comment: You can use this how-to that covers building non-default versions of PHP onto /opt and configuring FPM for that: https://hostingformula.net/how-to-install-multiple-php-version-php-5-2-php-5-5-php-5-6-and-php-7-in-single-vps-with-ubuntu-16-04/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to turn back the time, you can install Docker on this EC2 instance and then load one of the legacy Docker images for PHP 5.5,

https://github.com/devilbox/docker-php-fpm

Like others commented you should keep the sites away from the public internet, or they can be compromised easily.